# Set Value in JTable dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to create a JTable which "Analysis","Date" and "Price" the names of columns.
The value of Analysis and Price are recovered from the data base in my Database and the Date get the value of the current day.

I have created a class MyModel as the following :

```
package com.pack.classes;

import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

import com.pack.beans.MyElement;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    public static final String[] columnNames = {"Analyse", "Date d'analyse","Prix"};
    private final LinkedList<MyElement> list; 

    public MyModel() {
        list = new LinkedList<MyElement>();
    }

    public void addElement(MyElement e) {
        // Adds the element in the last position in the list
        list.add(e);
        fireTableRowsInserted(list.size()-1, list.size()-1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch(columnIndex) {
            case 0: return list.get(rowIndex).getAnalysis();
            case 1: return list.get(rowIndex).getDate();
            case 2: return list.get(rowIndex).getPrice();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

And i create a Bean MyElement as the following :

```
package com.pack.beans;

import java.util.Date;

public class MyElement {

    String analysis;
    Date date;
    Double price;

    public String getAnalysis() {
        return analysis;
    }
    public void setAnalysis(String analysis) {
        this.analysis = analysis;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

Here is a piece of my code which this class is used :

```
String sql = "Select name,number_b from analysis_tab  where  name ='" + idclicked + "'";
                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                    Date date = new Date();
                    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
                    PreparedStatement preparestate = database.con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ResultSet rs = preparestate.executeQuery();
                    MyModel mymodel = new MyModel();
                    String [] value = mymodel.columnNames;

                    MyElement e = new MyElement();
                    //e.setAnalysis(name);
                    e.setDate(date);
                    //e.setPrice("number_b");
```

As a result i obtain a Table with 3 coloumn "A","B" and "C".I don't know hence these name comes!!! 
Should you tell me how can i put my columns names "Analyse", "Date d'analyse","Prix" as a header in my Table?Am I on the right path??

Comment: Read [tutorial for `JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: do what? create a JTable? search for [oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: I just add a getColumnNames methode in MyModel class and it's work  :)

Comment: I have a problem, when i add a new elemet the previous element will be overwritten.How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Quit cross posting: http://www.coderanch.com/t/645524/GUI/java/Define-header-JTable-set

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the [DefaultTableModel](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CreateDefaultTableModel.htm)?
It is powerful than using only jtable.

// insert column name

```
defaultTableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[]{"Analyse", "Date d'analyse","Prix"});
```

And.. Your sql is statement type! If you can, change sql style like below.

```
String sql = "Select name,number_b from analysis_tab  where  name ='" + idclicked + "'";
```

**=>**

```
String sql = "Select name,number_b from analysis_tab  where  name = ?"
PreparedStatement preparestate = database.con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, idclicked);
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Check the "PreparedStatement" and "Statement"! :)